# Convert HashMap with POJO as value to JSON String

Tags: java, json

I have to convert a hashmap which has a POJO as a value.

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,VisualizerBean>> visualizerMap = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,VisualizerBean>>();
```

JSONObject histoGramJsonData = new JSONObject(visualizerMap);

**But the json I get prints the class name,**

"(39.995,40.185]":

```
{
    "_type": "JavaClass",
    "contentSum": null,
    "count": null,
    "_classname": "com.fractal.cascade.chart.didq.VariableVisualizerNodeModel$VisualizerBean",
    "class": "com.fractal.cascade.chart.didq.VariableVisualizerNodeModel$VisualizerBean",
    "contentMean": null
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to be using Gson or Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; if that's a problem for you, you may want to use another json library such as Gson or Jackson.

Comment: Used Gson .Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0):

Is this Android?

Android doc says:

> Values may be any mix of JSONObjects, JSONArrays, Strings, Booleans, Integers, Longs, Doubles or NULL.

As `com.fractal.cascade.chart.didq.VariableVisualizerNodeModel$VisualizerBean` is not anything from above, it will call `@Override toString()` of that class.

Comment: This is not an Android application.

I did overide toString() method 

    @Override
      public String toString() {
       HashMap<String,Object>   map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
       map.put("count",this.count.get());
       map.put("contentSum",this.contentSum);
       map.put("contentMean",getContentMean());
       return map.toString();
      }
But the output I get is the same.

Comment: Then I would use Gson. It serializes your POJOs in a proper way